# how to push emement of hashmap in stack

Tags: java

recently i am trying to push the hashmap element in the stack in java but every time i push the new element in the stack then all the elements in the stack is replaced with the recently pushed element.

here is my code:

```
state.previousState = dotPosColor;
state.pushState();
state.getElement();
public void pushState(){
    undos.push(previousState);
    Log.d("test","First->"+undos.firstElement().toString());
    Log.d("test","Last->"+undos.lastElement().toString());
    redos.clear();
}
```

Comment: Which version of java it is? some nightly build :-p

Comment: @sanbhat It could be Java, given suitable definitions.

Comment: actully it's andoird, but the part i asked is of java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> recently i am trying to push the hashmap element in the stack in java but every time i push the new element in the stack then all the elements in the stack is replaced with the recently pushed element.

I'm going to use my crystal ball and tell you that you are declaring your intermediate variable **globally**, when it needs to be **local**. ie:

```
for( some loop stuff here )
{
    Object o = hashMap.get("fwerin");
}
```